# NuGet package version is ignored when building

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am using VS 2017. I have this line in my `packages.config` file.

```
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I got this error my trying to start my .net application.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Because `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause` really does not exist in version 5.2.1.0. But it seem NuGet simply ignores the version specification, and always loads the latest version.

I have tried to clean NuGet caches, clean and rebuild entire solution, and restart computer...

Is there anything else I can do?

## Update

One strange thing I observed in VS 2017. Notice the differences of the icons for `System.Data` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. When I try to check the properties of the latter, VS says the package is not installed, which it clearly did. The build went successful, but the application just wont load the right version.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the path in the properties of the reference `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to us?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Please see my update

Comment: thanks for you reply. Have you add your project in to the source control? It seems you add the packages folder into the source control, you can use the command line `Update-Package -Id <package_name> –reinstall` in the package manager console to reinstall the references, then you may get the error log, if you get it you can share it and to resolve this issue, you can remove the packages folder from source control and delete the packages folder then use `Update-Package -Id <package_name> –reinstall` again.

Comment: Yes I use Git for source control. I did `update-package -reinstall` already. There's no error, but it did not fix the issue either. I did `uninstall-package -force` for all packages, but they still show up in VS and the project still builds successfully.

Comment: That is weird. How about manually remove those references from References node? And manually clear the `HintPath` entries in the project file, then reinstall those packages with nuget.

Comment: I removed all the things that could possible reference to any of those packages. However, they still find their way back to my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166068/discussion-between-leo-liu-msft-and-davidshen84).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, it is still unclear why VS cannot handle the changes of the NuGet packages, and why it thinks my project is using both `.Net Framework` and `.Net Standard` at the same time. I bet it is a but in VS, and hope MS can fix it soon.

Before that, installing Rider and use it to fix the packages, then went back to VS, and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps you can perform to check that the right version is loaded:

1. Rebuild your solution to make sure all NuGet packages are restored and that the started application is up to date (You already did that).
2. Check the tag `HintPath` for the reference in the project file that references the package. Just open the file in a text editor and look for an XML tag starting with `<Reference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`. Make sure that no version-specific reference is set or that the version matches the version in the `packages.config` file.
3. Check in the properties of the according reference in Visual Studio that it is resolved correctly. That means, there must be no yellow exclamation-mark icon on the reference in the solution explorer and in the properties of the reference, the `Path` entry must point to the installed package. Hence, the path should point to the `packages` directory inside your solution directory and therein into a directory `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.4.0.4.403061554`.

In most cases (from my experience), there is some mismatch between the reference in the `packages.config` file and in the project file. If that does not help, make sure that no other module is loaded by your application that has a reference to `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` in version `5.2.1.0`.

Comment: I have tried everything you said. What haunted me is that after I uninstalled all NuGet packages, the solution can still build...Eventually, I installed Rider, then reinstall the packages, and finally the problem is solved.

Comment: Might be that the used NuGet client didn't recognize the assembly reference in the project when uninstalling. Hence, the assembly reference might have still pointed to a local copy of the package... Do you see what changes happened in the project file?

Comment: The commit difference shows Rider only added back the Reference and Hint elements back. I think VS can do this as well, but it just won't work for me.

Comment: @davidshen84, since the workaround installing Rider can solve your problem, you can convert you comment to the answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.